# Excel 365 is replacing VBA project libraries

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-2010

I have an .xlsm file with macros that use a few project libraries, e.g. Microsoft Outlook 14.0 library. 
This file is updated by users and exchanged among them.
This file was created on a Windows 7 PC with Office 2010. 
When this file is opened on a Windows 10 PC with Office 365, the project libraries get replaced by their newer versions (365 versions).
After this, when a Windows 7 + Office 2010 user receives the same file and opens it, the macros don't work because the newer versions of libraries go missing.

How do I stop Office 365 from replacing the libraries and ensure that macros work on both PCs? Shouldn't Office 365 be backward compatible automatically?

If I understand this correctly, I am using late binding already:

```
'get user's email id
    Dim OutApp, olAllUsers, oExchUser, oentry, myitem As Object
    Dim User As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set olAllUsers = OutApp.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries
    User = OutApp.Session.CurrentUser.Name
    Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(User)
    Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()
    user_email = LCase(CStr(oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress))
```

**the error comes up on the last line**

Comment: Which error do you get and in which line. if using Late Binding make sure you have no references set to the "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 library" (remove them!).

Comment: Also note that `Dim OutApp, olAllUsers, oExchUser, oentry, myitem As Object` will only declare `myitem As Object` but all the others as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim OutApp As Object, olAllUsers As Object, oExchUser As Object, oentry As Object, myitem As Object`

Comment: Thanks. It could be that I have included the library for no reason and that alone is causing the problem. I will try removing it. Regarding declarations, I am surprised that I didn't know that and I have been declaring variables like this all the time. Thanks for this tip as well.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @dsauce Note that the line you used would work in VB.NET to declare multiple variables as objects (if you use that too) but VBA needs a type for **every** variable. That is a common confusion if people code in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this use Late Binding instead of Early Binding.

See …

- [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients)
- [VBA references and early binding vs late binding](http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/).

In Late Binding you would use

```
Set oAPP = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

to create an Outlook instance (without the need of setting a reference to the library) while Early Binding would use `Set oAPP = New Outlook.Application` and would need the reference.

So if you work with different versions of Outlook it is recommended to use Late Binding to prevent these odd behaviors. Note that you will lose intelli sense and instead of declaring a specific type `Dim oAPP As Outlook.Application` you would need to use `Object` for all Outlook specific types: `Dim oAPP As Object`

Comment: I added a piece of code I am using. As far as I understood, I am already using late binding.